# Form not picking up updated field value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to encrypt a form using a PGP Javascript API before sending it.
The PGP part works, but the form does not send the js-modified value of the form's fields.

Here is the Javascript :

```
<script>
        function encryptForm() {
            var password = document.getElementById("form_password");
            var email = document.getElementById("form_email");
            
            email.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            password.setAttribute("maxlength", "2000");
            password.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            
            var form = document.forms[index];
            var password = form.elements["password"];
            var email = form.elements["password"];
            
            encrypt(email.value).then(function(encrypted_msg) {
                    email.value = encrypted_msg;
            });
            encrypt(password.value).then(function(encrypted_msg) {
                    password.value = encrypted_msg;
            });
            
            form.submit();
            
            return true;
        }

        function encrypt(msg) {
            if (msg.indexOf("-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----") !== -1 && msg.indexOf("-----END PGP MESSAGE-----") !== -1) {
                return msg;
            } else {
                var key = `<?php printf($eassec->getPubkey('server')); ?>`;
                var publicKey = openpgp.key.readArmored(key).keys[0];
                return openpgp.encryptMessage(publicKey, msg).then(function(pgpMessage) {
                    return pgpMessage;
                });
            }
        } 
        </script>
```

And the form element :

```
<form onSubmit="return encryptForm()" class="EASboxForm" method="post">
                                <input id="form_email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="email adress" required autofocus>
                                <input id="form_password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" maxlength="72" required>
                                <input name="action" type="hidden" value="connect">
                                    <input type="image" class="EASboxFormSend" src="resources/pics/icons/form_continue.svg" alt="Continue">
                            </form>
```

(You can test it live at [REDACTED] - the PHP part will show an error message if the sent data ain't a valid PGP message, if everything is correct the hashed password and the email will show up)

Comment: You can use client-side JavaScript for encryption, but it's not terribly secure.

Comment: of course it doesn't, because you don't wait until encryption has finished before sending it.

Comment: Do not vandalize your own posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `encrypt()` is an asynchronous function, you have to wait for it to complete before submitting the form. You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for multiple promises to complete.

```
Promise.all([encrypt(email.value).then(function(encrypted_msg) {
    email.value = encrypted_msg;
  }),
  encrypt(password.value).then(function(encrypted_msg) {
    password.value = encrypted_msg;
  })
]).then(function() {
  form.submit();
});
```

You also need to `return false` from the `encryptForm()` function, to prevent the normal form submission.

Comment: No, it doesn't. `form.submit()` occurs immediately, before anything has changed. What you're seeing is that the browser updates the display while it's waiting for the server to process the submission.

Comment: It still sends everything in clear. I copied your exact code. What could be wrong ? :/

Comment: Can you provide a link to the encryption API so I can try to create a fiddle?

Comment: I need a public key to use in `var key`.

Comment: I just noticed that you have `return true` at the end of the `encryptForm()` function. Change that to `return false;` to prevent the normal form submission.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is, `function encrypt` is an asynchronous function as per your implementation. But the execution flow of the javascript is top to bottom. when the code reaches the submit, the values may not be ready. Hence you may need to slightly change the flow of the program as shown below.

```
encrypt(email.value).then(function(encrypted_msg) {
  email.value = encrypted_msg;

  encrypt(password.value).then(function(encrypted_msg) {
    password.value = encrypted_msg;

    form.submit();
  });

});
```

Comment: Can you put a breakpoints at form.sumbit() and check the values of email and password, before the form is submitted

Comment: What's the browser are you using it for testing?. If it's Chrome then go to developer tools and select your js from source. Put a break point and execute the code. When the execution hit your break point at form.submit, check the values of email and password. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Ok so first fix those syntax errors and then do the suggestion I told.

Comment: What happened ? :)